# Accidently make ls colors (folders, files, links...) to white

Tags: command-line, colors, ls

[image]I accidentally delete/change LS colors when listing directories with the 'ls' command, so I tried the command "ls --color=auto" it works temporarily because when I reboot my terminal ls colors return to just white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your `~/.bashrc` contains a section that defines the `ls` and `grep` commands to run in color mode.

The default `.bashrc` configuration file can be found in the directory `/etc/skel`, and from here you can take the relevant section and add it back to your `~/.bashrc` to restore the default behavior with color support:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]
then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

Comment: thanks! ls colors work again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how Ubuntu works with the default bash alias definitions.

Usually, in your "`~/.bashrc`" file, you have a source command of "`/etc/bashrc`". There are many default parameters in this file. And this file load "`/etc/profile.d/*`" files who contains aliases definitions.

So, do you have modified (accidently) your "`~/.bashrc`" file or your "`~/.bash_profile`" ? The last one usually source "`~/.bashrc`".

If you are non interrested to load default system files (in "`/etc`"), you cloud add the alias definition "`alias ls 'ls --color=auto'`" in your own "`~/.bashrc`".