# Alacritty Color Schemes Not Working

Tags: command-line, bash, themes, colors

**Color Change for Alacritty Terminal not working.** Usually it works by just changing a configuration file and saving.

[image]

This started occurring after I used this command:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;35:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Which I got from [this thread here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) when I was attempting to change the color of my directories and folders

I have tried deleting and recreating the alacritty.yml file, but it does not work.
I am under the assumption that the command did something, but am not sure of the fix.

I have also tried commenting out this code in my .bashrc file from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371053/accidently-make-ls-colors-folders-files-links-to-white):

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases

if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]
then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

I also do not have **dircolors** directory. Any ideas?